# shlock not found

Tags: apt, package-management, lock

I'm trying to use a script for backing up btrfs, and it uses `shlock`

here is the script: 
[btrfs-subvolume-backup](http://marc.merlins.org/linux/scripts/btrfs-subvolume-backup)

now it says i need the inn package, and I've triedn installing it, but still no `shlock`

according to [ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/shlock.1.html#contenttoc5) `shlock` should be in inn2 package, which I have also tried with no success.

So where can I find that package to install (64 bit pc) or how to fix the script to have the same functionalaty without `shlock`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu Packages index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=shlock&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), it could be in the `inn` or `inn2` packages. In both cases, from the [list of files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/inn/filelist), `shlock` is at:

```
/usr/lib/news/bin/shlock
```

Perhaps you need to use the full path, or set the PATH accordingly.

Comment: Marc Merlins says "If you don't have shlock, install inn, copy shlock out of it, and then delete it :)" from http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-03-19_Btrfs-Tips_-Btrfs-Scrub-and-Btrfs-Filesystem-Repair.html